# How to get redux store or redux dispatch in CLASS react component using typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I know how to to dispatch and get store using functional component. There is a great documentation about it [here](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#createasyncthunk)

But what about class component? How to get store and fire dispatch using class component. There is nothing said about it.

Lets say I defined hooks.ts:

```
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { RootState, AppDispatch } from './store/store';

export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>()
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector
```

And I need this functional component make as class:

```
import {useAppDispatch, useAppSelector} from "../../../hooks"
import { setRelease } from "./../store/factorySlice/factorySlice"
const X: React.FC = () => {
  const {selectedRelease} = useAppSelector(store => store.factory)
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch()

  return (
    <>
     {selectedRelease}
     <button onClick={() => dispatch(setRelease())}>Click</button>
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `Redux Toolkit` is our official recommended approach for writing Redux logic. It *wraps around the `Redux` core*, and contains packages and functions that we think are essential for building a Redux app

You can use it with class component by using `react-redux`'s `connect` API:

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { setRelease } from "./../store/factorySlice/factorySlice"

class X extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {this.props.selectedRelease}
        <button onClick={() => this.props.dispatch(setRelease())}>Click</button>
      </>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  selectedRelease: state.factory.selectedRelease
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(X);
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the first implementation. You would connect the class component to the store like

> connect()(MyComponent)

Where Class is MyComponent